# jstree - open_node not getting fired on closed node

Tags: jstree

I need a way to display a node in jstree with a closed icon but when opened, the "open_node" event must be fired which will create child nodes via a local JSON store.

This is what I'm trying

```
$('#treediv').jstree({
        'core' : {
                'check_callback': true,
                'data':[{"id":"parent","text":"Parent Node","opened":false}]
        }
    });
$('#treediv').on('open_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
                  // logic to fetch children and create child nodes
              });
```

I do not want to make a direct AJAX call hence cannot use the load-by-AJAX option of jstree.

With the above code, the node is displayed with a closed icon but when i try to open, the event is not getting fired; probably because there are no children initially.

Please advise on how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide the node you want to create child nodes into with an id and perhaps use a dblClick() event for triggering your logic after?

```
$('#nodeId).dblClick(function(e) {
    //logic to fetch children and create child nodes
}
```

https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

Comment: The select_node event is getting fired when i click on the node so I can trigger the logic there but what I need is for the triangle icon (open/closed) to be displayed and when I open the node, the event should get fired to fetch children data and create the child nodes. And I need this without firing an AJAX call on opening the node.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `open_node` event this way:

```
.on('open_node.jstree', function (e, obj) { 
    // remove dummy node that was used to enable collapsed icon
    $('#tree').jstree().delete_node('dummy');
    //add new data from json
    for(var i=0, len=newData.length; i<len; i++){
        var nodeId = $('#tree').jstree().create_node(obj.node.id, newData[i]);
    }
})
```

Check fiddle [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/2wLLL6hk/)